# Unable to run bundle exec rake

Tags: ruby, redmine, redmine-plugins

I'm trying to install backlogs module on my Redmine server, exactly following this guide: https://backlogs.github.io/www/en/installation.html

Though, that is what happens:

```
root@tannenfels:/var/www/redmine# bundle exec rake redmine:backlogs:install --trace
rake aborted!
Don't know how to build task 'redmine:backlogs:install' (see --tasks)
/var/www/redmine/.gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.3.1/lib/rake/task_manager.rb:59:in `[]'
/var/www/redmine/.gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.3.1/lib/rake/application.rb:159:in `invoke_task '
/var/www/redmine/.gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.3.1/lib/rake/application.rb:116:in `block (2 le vels) in top_level'
/var/www/redmine/.gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.3.1/lib/rake/application.rb:116:in `each'
/var/www/redmine/.gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.3.1/lib/rake/application.rb:116:in `block in to p_level'
/var/www/redmine/.gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.3.1/lib/rake/application.rb:125:in `run_with_th reads'
/var/www/redmine/.gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.3.1/lib/rake/application.rb:110:in `top_level'
/var/www/redmine/.gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.3.1/lib/rake/application.rb:83:in `block in run '
/var/www/redmine/.gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.3.1/lib/rake/application.rb:186:in `standard_ex ception_handling'
/var/www/redmine/.gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.3.1/lib/rake/application.rb:80:in `run'
/var/www/redmine/.gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.3.1/exe/rake:27:in `<top (required)>'
/var/www/redmine/.gem/ruby/2.3.0/bin/rake:23:in `load'
/var/www/redmine/.gem/ruby/2.3.0/bin/rake:23:in `<main>'
```

All dependencies seem to be resolved, and module tar.gz archive placed in right place. What I am doing wrong?

Comment: Backlogs are only supported for Redmine 2.0.4 currently. That being said, did you run the command from the root of your Redmine installation?
For detailed info, you can check the Redmine wiki https://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/RedmineRake
I hope it helps.

Comment: Yes, as it mentioned in guide.

Comment: Please follow the steps from here https://github.com/backlogs/redmine_backlogs/issues/718#issuecomment-9976190. This might resolve your problem.

Comment: No such line in Gemfile

Comment: Adding `gem "test-unit", "=1.2.3" if RUBY_VERSION >= "1.9"` did not help, resulted in exception.